# LINQ query to find elements from a list in a csv file

Tags: list, csv, linq, element, contains

I am trying to find if a any element of a first list is found for each line of a csv file

**First list :**

```
XX01235756777
YY01215970799
```

**Second list (that would be the csv file) :**

```
Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|Column_4|Column_5|Column_6|Column_7
VX|2022-06-09 11:50:55|Y|Y|N|TT56431254135|Microsoft
VX|2022-06-09 11:50:55|Y|Y|N|XX01235756777|Meta
VX|2022-06-09 11:50:55|Y|Y|N|YY18694654355|Nokia
VX|2022-06-09 11:50:55|Y|Y|N|OO01215970799|BlackStone
VX|2022-06-09 11:50:55|Y|Y|N|YY01215970799|Alphabet
```

**My code attempt :**

```
        List<string> filteredList = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(csvFilePath))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Any(x => isinList.Contains(x.ToString())))
                {
                    filteredList.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
        return filteredList;
```

**filteredList should be :**

```
VX|2022-06-09 11:50:55|Y|Y|N|XX01235756777|Meta
VX|2022-06-09 11:50:55|Y|Y|N|YY01215970799|Alphabet
```

I succeeded at finding a single element in each line of the csv file.

But I can't code the right LINQ to process if whole list is present in each line.

Any ideas or anywhere you can point me to would be a great help.

Comment: C# is a language of types. Your types look very suspicious to me. `line` is a `string` - what does that make the `x` in `.Any(x =>`? What does that mean for what you are testing?

Answer (score 1):

What you have ends up splitting the line from the csv file into characters and each character is checked against the isinList.  You should instead check if any string in the isinList exists in each line from the csv file.

```
List<string> filteredList = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(csvFilePath))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (isinList.Any(x => line.Contains(x)))
        {
            filteredList.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ, and the `File.ReadLines()` to read the lines in the file, you can filter as follows:

```
var filteredLines = File.ReadLines(csvFilePath)
                            .Where(line => isinList.Any(isin => line.Contains(isin)))
                            .ToList();
```

OTOH, if `isinList` is very large, or the CSV file is very long, and you know Column_6 is the only possible match, you might gain performance by using a `HashSet<string>` and testing only Column_6:

```
var isinSet = isinList.ToHashSet();
var filteredLines = File.ReadLines(csvFilePath)
                        .Where(line => isinSet.Contains(line.Split('|')[5]))
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, will implement and test it. questions : what size are you thinking about when you say very large for `isinList` ? and what size should the CSV be for you to consider it as very long ?

Comment: @Ekel That really depends on your environment - creating the `HashSet` takes a certain amount of time, but really speeds up the `Contains` test but the `Split` adds overhead as well. The break even point is dependent on speed of computer and disk. You could time the different options and measure.

Comment: @Ekel A quick test on my PC seems to indicate the two methods are about even at 12 items in `isinList` and 1000 lines and even with 1000 items and 10 lines, the `HashSet` is fast. So as long as you know you are only matching on column 6, I would say go with method 2.